# getting location of installed application vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i published an application in vb.net. the user will be able to install the application anywhere they choose on the computer (or perhaps not anywhere they choose but where ever the default location is). how can i programmatically get the location where the user installed the application? another words i need the application to know where it is running from. how do i detect that?

Comment: Wow, so many ways to achieve the same thing, via different means... +1 party!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In runtime, you can use:

```
Application.StartupPath
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Application.ExecutablePath
```

that will tell you where your .exe is. Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 because this helped me answer my own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782446/accessing-file-in-installation-directory-in-vb-net-code/26783880#26783880

Answer (score 5):

If your app is a Windows Forms app you can use the Application static class, as others have noted.  For other kinds of applications, use reflection:

```
Dim a = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
Dim location = a.Location
```

I had to do this the other day, works great.

Comment: Location returns the full path AND file name.  Call Path.GetDirectoryName to get just the path.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
Shared ReadOnly AppDirectory As String = _
     Path.GetDirectoryName(New Uri(GetType(Program).Assembly.CodeBase).LocalPath)
```

Comment: what do u think of Hanin's answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at

[Application.ExecutablePath Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath.aspx)

or

[AppDomain.BaseDirectory Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

If you put this code in your exe then it will give you the path of the exe.

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```