# Accessing file in installation directory in vb.net code

Tags: vb.net, installation

Thanks ahead of time for your help!

I have an installation project in my solution. The installation project includes files that I would like to include in the install directory (template files, README docs, etc.).

The template file, specifically, I would like to access in my code so that I can open it and populate it with real-time data. At run-time, how can I see where the user installed the application and access that template file?

Using Visual Studio 2010 (full version)

Language: VB.NET

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting location of installed application vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609815/getting-location-of-installed-application-vb-net)

Comment: Hey! Whoa, whoa! I did research, couldn't find an answer, posted the question, found the answer and resolved the open question by refering to another answer. I didn't gain or lose reputation or anything and it was all my doing - shouldn't get down-voted for that :/ @Creator

Comment: Don't think if somebody marks a question as a duplicate he will also down vote.Its the same question as the other on so this one should be closed. that's all.

Answer (score 3):

Your .net software installed in  client pc 
At the time of installation path get and add your images template.doc etc file in resources folder of applications folder and access fileof dynamically in client pc

> `string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);`

and get path of installation software after that use resources folder to access it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can find what I need here: [getting location of installed application vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609815/getting-location-of-installed-application-vb-net)

This will allow me to get the filepath of the installation directory at least. From there I can open the template since I know the name of the template ahead of time.